# How to check scanf two integers in c

Tags: c, int, scanf

I have a problem, that I need to scan two integers in one line divided by a space, so the code looks something like this:

```
scanf("%d %d",&integer1,&integer2);
```

And in this code I need to check whether there were scanned two integers. Can someone help me? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Read manual page of `scanf`. It returns the number of successfully scanned elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `scanf()` reads the space there is no meaning in giving space. If you want to read two integers `scanf("%d %d",&integer1,&integer2);` and `scanf("%d%d",&integer1,&integer2);` both will help you.

**It will accept the following inputs:**

```
1 2
12 22
3 2 5 //EOF
```

your program will pass only after reading two integers. You don't need to check anything.
**To eliminate `EOF`**

By default `scanf` returns number of values read so make use of it.

```
if(scanf("%d%d",&integer1,&integer2) != 2)
{
   //if more than two values are entered
   //perform some error handling
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: What if there is EOF in stdin?

Comment: And what if the program pass even in case, that I try to scan char or double? So when I need to avoid the situation, that other type is scanned and print some warning or so?